# Why is eclipse's "Maven - Update Project" trying to build the deploy goal?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a multi-module maven project that's been imported into eclipse (Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)) and from time to time, I need to perform a "Maven -> Update project".   Unfortunately, this results in a maven build error related to the deploy plugin that I'm using.   I need to use an alternate plugin in order to deploy my project's artifacts to JFrog's bintray repository.
Here is an example of the error that I'm seeing in my eclipse console window:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Execution error (com.carrotgarden.maven:bintray-maven-plugin:1.5.20191113165555:deploy:default:deploy)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Execution error
    at com.carrotgarden.maven.bintray.BaseExecute.execute(BaseExecute.scala:30)
    at com.carrotgarden.maven.bintray.BaseExecute.execute$(BaseExecute.scala:18)
    at com.carrotgarden.maven.bintray.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.scala:26)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$7(MavenImpl.java:1380)

...

Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog:jar:99-20200508.153213-1 from/to bintray (https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/ibm-cloud-sdks/platform-services-java-sdk/com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog): Failed to transfer https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/ibm-cloud-sdks/platform-services-java-sdk/com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog/com/ibm/cloud/global-catalog/99-SNAPSHOT/global-catalog-99-20200508.153213-1.jar. Error code 400, Bad Request
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at com.carrotgarden.maven.bintray.DeployMojo.protected$deploy(DeployMojo.scala:141)
    at com.carrotgarden.maven.bintray.DeployMojo.$anonfun$executeDeploy$1(DeployMojo.scala:141)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog:jar:99-20200508.153213-1 from/to bintray (https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/ibm-cloud-sdks/platform-services-java-sdk/com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog): Failed to transfer https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/ibm-cloud-sdks/platform-services-java-sdk/com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog/com/ibm/cloud/global-catalog/99-SNAPSHOT/global-catalog-99-20200508.153213-1.jar. Error code 400, Bad Request
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:211)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog:jar:99-20200508.153213-1 from/to bintray (https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/ibm-cloud-sdks/platform-services-java-sdk/com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog): Failed to transfer https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/ibm-cloud-sdks/platform-services-java-sdk/com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog/com/ibm/cloud/global-catalog/99-SNAPSHOT/global-catalog-99-20200508.153213-1.jar. Error code 400, Bad Request
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:856)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: io.takari.aether.connector.TransferException: Failed to transfer https://bintray.com/api/v1/maven/ibm-cloud-sdks/platform-services-java-sdk/com.ibm.cloud:global-catalog/com/ibm/cloud/global-catalog/99-SNAPSHOT/global-catalog-99-20200508.153213-1.jar. Error code 400, Bad Request
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.handleResponseCode(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:372)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.access$8(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:362)
    ... 44 more
    pom.xml /public-global-catalog  line 5  Maven Build Problem
```

Line 5 of the module pom file referenced in the error is the beginning of the `<parent>` section of the module's pom.
I'm not surprised about the `Failed to deploy` and `Failed to transfer` errors because I don't have the necessary creds in my local sandbox to do an actual deploy, and my project's snapshot artifacts are not present in the bintray repository in any event.

I'm not sure why "Maven -> Update project" is trying to build the "deploy" goal in the first place.  I certainly do not want it to :)
Anyone have a clue as to how I can prevent that?   Can I configure the goal used by the "Maven -> update project"?

Comment: Can you post the `build` section of your pom.xml? A look at the `deploy` plugin might give some idea.

Comment: Actually, the project is on github.com, located here: https://github.com/IBM/platform-services-java-sdk, with the build section of my parent pom located here: https://github.com/IBM/platform-services-java-sdk/blob/8a967893b5aded958a9bc7f6ce4080da27c7a80b/pom.xml#L321 .
Note that this problem didn't start occurring until after I introduced the bintray-maven-plugin to perform deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I received some help from the eclipse m2e project's mailing list.  One way to avoid the errors that I'm seeing inside eclipse is to add `<?m2e ignore?>` to the plugin's `<execution>` configuration, like this:

```
<execution>
    <?m2e ignore?>
    <id>bintray-deploy</id>
    <phase>deploy</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

This apparently tells the eclipse m2e plugin to simply ignore this goal when updating the project configuration inside eclipse.

Comment: this worked? If so, do you have the link to that email response?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/m2e-users/msg05832.html